# Can more than 24 knights of each color be placed on a chessboard without any pieces attacking opposite color?

Tags: chess, checkerboard

The maximal number of knights of a single color that can be placed on a chessboard without any knight being one knights-move away from any other is 32; such a position may easily be achieved by placing all 32 knights on squares of the same color.

If one uses both black pieces and white pieces, it's possible to place 24 knights of each color (48 total) on the board without any knight being attacked by a knight of the opposite color.  One simple approach is to place 24 white knights on the first three ranks, and 24 black knights on the last three.  That position is but one of many, which can accommodate 24 knights of each color.

Is it possible to either place 24 knights of one color and more than 24 of the other or prove the impossibility of doing so?  Note that if one may arbitrarily choose the number of knights of each color, one could easily place 62 knights (61 white and one black) or, for that matter, 64 (all white).  To be of interest, I think it is possible to rank solutions by the number of pieces in the "shorter" army and then by the number of pieces in the other.

Comment: I think the answer is actually proving that its not possible more than actually placing the pieces

Comment: @skv, indeed. it's not possible

Answer (score 11):

Ok let me stick my neck out, I would love to be proved wrong on this, but there are only a few ways (3 unique ways) 24 Knights of each side can be placed on the board i.e. without attacking any of the other coloured pieces

[image]

[image]

[image]

Other combinations of swapping colours and rotating the boards could be achieved.

And even theoretically 48 squares are occupied by knights, leaving just 16, given the fact that a knight in the edge attacks 4 squares and in the center attacks 8, it is logical to understand that 2 and 4 of these have to fall in "enemy" territory so to say.  so even ensuring an overlap of 2 knights per square, we are talking of 8 squares per colour being "attacked" over and above the squares occupied by their own forces, for both sides this is 16 squares.

Hence it is not possible to place more than 24 knights per side

Comment: You are right, but I meant those in the "middle corner" as in edge :) I will edit

Comment: There is at least one other possibility (See my edit)

Comment: @M.Herzkamp appreciate it and accepted the edit, but I think its your answer :), I mean I did not come up with that thought

Comment: It does not improve the score :( So it just aims to complete your answer. And now it looks ugly ;)

Comment: ok made it look pretty :) I would not say it was ugly, but yes inconsistent

Comment: And the symmetric version? ;) I will stop nagging now.

Comment: Oh, I just realized, this can be rotated as well, so you have four symmetric solutions like this.

Comment: And then there are two additional solutions for mirroring your 1 and 4. Perhaps it would be best to show only one sample each and state how many operations will lead to distinct valid solutions.

Comment: I think there are quite a few more solutions.  For example, unless I'm missing something, one could move g3 and g6 to h4 and h5, respectively, while leaving everything else as-is (or do likewise with b3/b6 to a4/a5); doing one or both of those would then enable some additional changes.

Comment: @supercat agree, that is the reason I have written that theoretical part, even if you ensure overlaps all the way through, there has to be 8 squares for each colour to be left out, but as I said, I would love to be proved wrong here

Comment: @skv: You suggest that there reflections and other isomorphisms exist, but fails to mention that there are a variety of positions that can be achieved iteratively picking up one piece of each color, and then setting them down on formerly-empty squares that are no longer under attack.  As for your explanation, I could understand such an approach that position where black and white armies were mirror images of each other must have eight squares of each color, but I'm not seeing how any sort of "proof" holds together absent such a constraint.  Perhaps a little more detail would help me see it?

Comment: @supercat yes you are right about the combinations, but about the second point, in your question you mention that if they are not equal then the "smaller" army would be considered, so I thought you are ruling out that option

Comment: @skv: The black an white armies both need to have at least 24 pieces, but that wouldn't imply any particular sort of symmetry in the arrangement.  Some legal arrangements of pieces are not symmetrical, and I don't yet see any proof that such an arrangement couldn't allow 24 of one color and 25 of the other.

Comment: @skv: I've certainly seen quite a few puzzles where intuition would suggest that there should exist an optimal solution that is symmetrical, but where in fact breaking symmetry allows a better solution.  I don't think that's the case here, but I see no particular reason to rule out the possibility.

Comment: I agree, I would love to see such a solution too

Comment: @skv: I wonder how one would prove that all solutions with 24 knights of each color must be rotationally antisymmetric [i.e. rotating the board 180 degrees must be equivalent to swapping colors]?  I can't find any counter-examples, but that's hardly a proof.